# How to Align Div properly

Tags: html, css, reactjs

Im trying to align my DIV to form a bullet chart. I created a sample Data that I will used for the bullet chart to become dynamic
here is the code:

```
      {bulletchartdata.map(
        (item,index)=>{
            return(
    <div>
        <div className="satisfactory"style={{width:item.satisfactoryVal,height:20,backgroundColor:'#f2f2f2'}}/> 
            <div className="badcolor"style={{width:item.badVal,height:20,backgroundColor:'#d8d6d6'}}/>
                <div className="measure"stlye={{width:item.performanceVal,height:10,backgroundColor:'#8c8c8c'}}> 
                    <div className="target"style={{width:item.symbolMarker,width:1,height:15,backgroundColor:'#000000'}}>     
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
            );

        }
    )}
```

here is the sample DATA That I want to pass in the div rather than declaring it in the CSS:

```
    export const bulletchartdata = [
    { performanceVal: 100, symbolMarker: 100, badVal: 300, satisfactoryVal: 150}
```

here is the CSS:(Now I dont want to use this CSS(that is why some line are in "comment") since I'm trying to input all the styles inside the DIV(check the div codes)

```
    .satisfactory {     
      /* width:300px; */
     /*  height:20px; */
      background-color:#f2f2f2;  /* satisfactory */
      position:relative;
    }


    .badcolor {    
      /* width:160px; */
      /* height:20px; */
      background-color:#d8d6d6; /* badcolor */
      position:relative;
      bottom:0px;
    }


    .measure{  
      width:275px;
      height:7px;
      background-color:#8c8c8c; /* Performance Measure */
      position:inherit;
      right:0px;
      top:9px; 
      bottom:0px;
    }

    .target{   
      width:1px;
     /*  height:20px; */
      background-color:#000000;  /* target */
      position: inherit;
      left:240px;
      right:0px;
      top:-6.5px; 
      bottom:0px;
    }
```

[Here is the Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSwwl.png)

[I want it to look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0udZj.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use `position:absolute` for the inner divs...and also change your markup *(no need to wrap every div inside)*....

```css
.satisfactory {
  position: relative;
}

.satisfactory div {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="satisfactory" style="background: #f2f2f2;width: 300px;height: 40px;">
  <div class="badcolor" style="background-color:#d8d6d6;height:40px;width:150px;"></div>
  <div class="measure" style="background-color:#8c8c8c;height:10px;width:250px;top:15px"></div>
  <div class="target" style="background-color:#000000;height:40px;width:1px;left:200px;top:0;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello Sir @Bhuwan, I tried it and still get the same result. I changed the format that is acceptible for reactjs, because im using reactjs.

Here is the Code :
<div>

<div className="satisfactory"style{{backgroundColor:'#f2f2f2',width:300,height:40}}/>
<div className="badcolor"style{{backgroundColor:'#d8d6d6',height:40,width:150}}></div>
<div className="measure"style{{backgroundColor:'#8c8c8c',height:10,width:250,top:15}}></div>
<div className="target"style{{backgroundColor:'#000000',height:40,width:1,left:200,top:0}}></div>

</div>

Comment: @FahadBayabao Actually you will need to wrap the `.badcolor`, `.measure`, `.target` divs inside your `. satisfactory ` div....

Comment: Hi Sir @Bhuwan. YES IT WORKED. I PUT THE OTHER DIVS INSIDE MY MAIN DIV. SUPEEER THANK YOU SIR